# Go to location when click button on Bing maps Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want when click button then go to Location reserved or select in combobox. This example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh830432(v=msdn.10) but i don't know code behind for **ChangeMapView_Click** or full code for xaml below. Another know code behind, maybe share with me. Thank you!

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.SwitchMapViews"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
Width="1024" Height="768">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <m:Map x:Name="myMap" CredentialsProvider="<strong>INSERT_YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY</strong>" 
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Padding="5"
           Center="39.3683,-95.2734,0.0000" ZoomLevel="4.000" AnimationLevel="None" Mode="AerialWithLabels"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnNorthAmerica" Click="ChangeMapView_Click" Tag="39.3683,-95.2734,0.0000 4.0000"
                 Margin="5">
            <TextBlock>North America</TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewYork" Click="ChangeMapView_Click" Tag="40.7199,-74.0030,0.0000 12.0000" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock>New York</TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnSanFrancisco" Click="ChangeMapView_Click" Tag="37.6801,-122.3395,0.0000 11.0000" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock>San Francisco</TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnVancouver" Click="ChangeMapView_Click" Tag="49.2765,-123.1030,0.0000 14.0000" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock>Vancouver</TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="AnimationLevel_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="1" Margin="10" Height="20">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="None" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Full" />
        </ComboBox>

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="0.9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="0.9" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Latitude: " Padding="5" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLatitude" Text="" IsReadOnly="True" Background="LightGray"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Longitude: " Padding="5" Foreground="White" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtLongitude" Text="" IsReadOnly="True" Background="LightGray"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It seems obvious from the documentation page that you linked to call one of the SetView method overloads, most certainly [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709340(v=msdn.10)). Parse the value of the pressed Button's Tag property to get the desired location, heading and zoom level. No idea why they are not including the event handler in the sample.

Comment: @Clemens you can get for me a code behind example with your link send, i want use in mainwindow.cs

Comment: You can change the language of this example from XAML to C# (there is a combobox above the title, slightly to the right) and you will be able to function definitions

Comment: @radoslawik Well spotted! I missed that entirely.